# React Native AsyncStorage First Value Null

Tags: reactjs, react-native, asyncstorage

I am getting local record with AsyncStorage. But when calling get with get, the first null of the state is returned. Then it gives value (value).

```
componentDidMount(){

    if(this.props.gelenSabitIlce){
        var processLak = this.props.gelenSabitIlce.toString();
        AsyncStorage.setItem('nole1', processLak);

    }
    AsyncStorage.getItem('nole1').then((value) => {
        var obj = JSON.stringify(value);
        this.setState({ nole1: obj });
    }).done();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`AsyncStorage` is - like the name says - asynchronous. You're executing your code in `componentDidMount` synchronously, therefore you are getting null.

The correct way of doing that would either be using **async/await** (check docs: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/asyncstorage.html for details) pattern or, according to your current code, something like this:

```
componentDidMount() {
  const { gelenSabitIlce } = this.props;

  if (gelenSabitIlce) {
    const processLak = gelenSabitIlce.toString();
    AsyncStorage.setItem('nole1')
      .then(this.getValue);
  }
}

getValue() {
  AsyncStorage.getItem('nole1')
    .then((value) => {
      const nole1 = JSON.stringify(value);
      this.setState({ nole1 });
    }).done();  
}
```